# Add border-bottom: 1px solid #FF to Sub Menu on hover in CSS Horizontal Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure as to how to add a border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF to all sub menu items when hovered?

```
#menu{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 30px;
   left: 0px;
   font-size: 8pt;
}
#menu ul{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
#menu li{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
} 

#menu li a{
   width:120px;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height: 20px;
   background-color: #A9BBD3;
   color: #FFF;
} 

#menu li a:hover{
   background-color: #446087;
} 

#menu ul ul{
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    width: 115px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
   visibility:visible;
}
#menu > ul > li > a{
    text-align:center;
}

<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#nogo">File</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Save</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Edit</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Add</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Reports</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS and see if this helps:

​    #menu ul li > ul a:hover {
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    } ​

Comment: Works like a charm. I was kind of thinking, it'd probably be best just to apply it onto the main top menu on hover, so it reminds the user as to what menu they are using, and it will look better for styling. How would you just apply it on a hover, just to the top menu (index menu) only?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. You want the border-bottom to appear only under the top-level menu items? Or do you want it to apply to all hovered menu-items? It seems to me that putting the border below the main menu item isn't going to make it much clearer than it already is... maybe unifying the background color between the main menu item and its revealed children might be clearer, but it also seems that it would be fairly obvious which main menu item the children belong to, since they're right below it and match it in width.